# RequestContext.RouteData and Request.UrlReferrer info is lost on FormMethod.Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to post a form with one of the variables being the Action of the previous URL, however whenever I POST it, the variable becomes null. How can I persist that info at least until it reaches the POST Action?

I've tried using both `Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"]` and `Request.UrlReferrer` to get the Action.

In my View I'm trying to POST a file, Action name, and an id:

`Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Expenses", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", actionName = actionName, id = idInt })`

If I keep it the way it is, the Action name is null, but if I remove the **FormMethod.Post** portion from the BeginForm method, the Action name is posted successfully and the file is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `Html.BeginForm` helper method incorrectly! You mixed route values and html attributes to a single object !

Your current call matches the below overload

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    FormMethod method,
    IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes
)
```

The last parameter is the **htmlAttributes**. So with your code, it will generate the form tag markup like this

```
<form action="/Expenses/Edit" actionname="someActionName" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                                                                     id="22" method="post">

</form>
```

You can see that `Id` and `action` became 2 attributes of the form !

Try [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary,System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary%7BSystem.String,System.Object%7D%29) where you can specify both route values and htmlAttributes

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Home",  new {  actionName = "Edit", id = 34 },
                                 FormMethod.Post,new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", }))
{
        <input type="submit"/>
}
```

which will generate the correct form action attribute value using the route values you provided.